# Convert Text File to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I want to open a text file within Pycharm (keywords.txt), and lets say this text file contained a list of words, with corresponding numerical values, thus the text file was of the following form:

```
apple, 3
banana, 5 
happy, 7
tiger, 9
```

(with numerical values ranging from 1-10)

I understand that in order to open this file(in read mode), we would do the following:

```
with open('keywords.txt','r') as f:
```

How could I read over each individual word, on each line of the text file, and then store it into a dictionary as a keyword, and then also store its corresponding numerical value?

For example:

```
dictionary = {'apple':'3','banana':'5','happy':'7','tiger':'9'}
```

What I tried:

```
with open('keywords.txt','r') as k:
    size_to_read = 1
    k_text = k.read(size_to_read)
    while len(k_text) > 0:
            if k_text.isalpha:
                keywordic = dict.fromkeys({'k_text'})
                print(keywordic)
            k_text = k.read(size_to_read)
```

I didn't really know where I was going with this...

It just prints a bunch of the following:

```
{'k_text': None}
```

Comment: Tried anything to solve this?

Comment: The methods I've tried haven't been too kind to me haha

Comment: Humour us, post your best attempt.

Comment: Okay, it seems you do not have enough of an understanding of this language to program with it. Obviously writing an answer isn't going to solve anything because it does not correct your misunderstandings and misconceptions. Look [here](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) first. Learn about loops, data structures (look at the dictionary docs), understand when to use loops and when to use conditionals. Understand the difference between a method and attribute. Understand how to _call_ functions. `k_text.isalpha` is not going to do what you expect.

Comment: Haha thanks. Just a first-year undergraduate student in CS who probably should have went to more lectures.

Answer (score 4):

```
def readFile(filename):
    # Dict that will contain keys and values
    dictionary =  {}
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.strip().split(", ")
            dictionary[s[0]] = int(s[1])
        return dictionary
```

This works by opening the file, removing whitespace with `strip()`, splitting the strings into lists using `strip()` and then setting the key to the first part of the string array `s`, which is the fruit, and the value to the second part after casting it to an `int`.

Comment: Receiving the following error: dictionary[s[0]] = (int(s[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are lines guaranteed to be of the correct or same format? "string, #"?

Comment: Yes, each line will have string,integer -in that format

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a file line by line using `for line in myfile:`.

```
dictionary = {}
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(",")
        dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data_dict = { line.split(",")[0] : line.split(",")[1] for line in open('keywords.txt') }
```

Answer (score 0):

just read the file line by line, and for each line of string, use `split(', ') to get a list of first and second item in the line, then you can store the two strings in a dictionary, and you can convert the second string into a integer if necessary.